# Removing specific rows from table without using DELETE

Tags: sql, hive, partition

I am working in a company and I need to find a way to delete specific rows from table without using DELETE function.

So I was thinking to use partition and then remove it using drop partition if exists:

```
select *,   count(validity_date) over(partition by another_column) as indicator from schema.table
```

Which worked, but when I try dropping the partition using

```
ALTER TABLE schema.table DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION(year(validity_date) = '2022');
```

I get an error saying

> mismatched input '(' expecting set null in drop partition statement

So my question is there any other way to remove specific rows from a table without using the delete function?

Thank you !

Comment: This is gross. I feel for you for having to hack your way to get rid of rows.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your query - missing a closing parenthesis in the end.

```
ALTER TABLE schema.table DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION(year(validity_date) = '2022'));
```

These are the only two options to delete the data : Either via `drop partition` or `delete` query

*P.S.  Hive supports ACID transactions like delete and update records/rows on Table only **Hive 0.14** version onwards.*

Comment: Hi friend, I don't see why I miss parenthesis because I've opened 2 and closed 2, but I added anyway and still get the same error:  mismatched input '(' expecting set null in drop partition statement. Can you please advise?